# Iron Router , change URL without changing browser history

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Using iron router version 0.9.4 
How to update URL query parameters without changing the browser history?

I have a bunch of select boxes which can update the URL query parameters.  In some cases I'd like to update the URL without adding an additional entry into window.history.  A lot of templates are dependent on the Router.current().params reactive variable, so I need to update that as well when changing the route.

Answer (score 6):

Iron Router has an optional parameter in the Router.go function which you can pass in `{replaceState:true}` .   This will update the URL without storing the URL change in the window's history.

This is working in Iron Router 0.9.4

```
var path = Router.path('myRoute',{_id: myId}, {query: myParams});
Router.go(path, {replaceState: true});
```

If you are on a newer version of Iron Router, the order of arguments has probably changed a little, according to this [github issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/461) this would be the new order :

```
Router.go(path, {}, {replaceState:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla JavaScript:

```
window.history.replaceState(yourNewUrl);
```

Here is some [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method). As it's a modern feature, if you want to support older browsers, you can [use a polyfill](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/html5-history-api).

Comment: thanks, normally that would work but in my case I have some templates which are dependent on the Router.current().params ,  so I needed to also update the Router params.